# WinSCP - SFTP script to backup the newest files

Tags: powershell, backup, sftp, winscp

I have call recordings on AWS but I'm only given 10 GB of space so I would like to have a script which will SFTP to the Amazon AWS and only copy the newest files to my NAS sitting in the office. I can than use Windows Task Scheduler to run the scripts once a week.

The idea is that after all space on AWS is populated it starts to deleting the oldest recordings, so I want to prevent it and only use AWS as a buffer to store the current recordings and my NAS as a main storage. My script will be running every week/month to copy only the newest files in order to prevent loosing any recordings.

Below I have described the logic of how I would like the script to behavior:

Establish an SFTP session

if destination directory doesn't contain any files create a full backup first

if destination does contain some files copy only missing files

Looking forward for any ideas, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use [`get` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get) with [`-neweronly` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get#neweronly):

```
open sftp://user:password@example.com/
get -neweronly /remote/path/* C:\local\path\*
```

For a very similar results, you can also use [`synchronize` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_synchronize):

```
synchronize local /remote/path C:\local\path
```

---

If you want to synchronize only recent files, you can add `-filemask=>2D` or similar.
See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#size_time